# Message Passing from NetBeans Plugin to C# WinForms Application

Tags: java, c#, netbeans

The short version of this question is, how can I send a message (a file path, for example) from a Java application (NetBeans plugin, to be specific) to an already-running C# WinForms executable application?

Some details.

I currently have a Windows application that I built (it's like a parser/editor for script files to help automate the process of script building using simple GUI tools for our test team).  In the application, you can load a file using the app's "Load" button, hotkey, drag/drop, etc.  You can also open the application from the command line with one or more file paths as parameters, and the app will launch with the given files already loaded.

On request, I cobbled together a NetBeans plugin (Java) that grabs the file path of the file that is currently in focus in NetBeans, and then executes my application with the focused file's path as parameter.  This allows me to launch my app directly from NetBeans and open the file being edited in NetBeans in my app.

So what my app can do:
Launch with file loaded from CLI parameter
Load file from internal load command on-the-fly

What it can't do (what I want to add):
Load file in running instance from external message parameter on-the-fly
Load file in running instance from CLI message parameter on-the-fly

MSMQ is a solution I can't use.  Saw it suggested in a lot of other threads.  Things to note are that the NetBeans plugin and my app will always be on the same system, but I can't get MSMQ on all target machines.

Comment: The usual solution to this sort of thing is to implement a "single-instance" app, and include functionality for the secondary instance (which normally would just check via named mutex whether there's already an instance running and if there is, set that instance as the active window and exit) to pass to the running instance the information to open the file. This can be done via normal Windows mechanisms (e.g. MSMQ, DDE, shared memory, named pipes, etc.); since you are implementing the real work in your main program, you're not limited to what Java supports.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  My application already uses a mutex to ensure only one instance can be run at a time, and that part is working smoothly.  I've been trying to figure out a way to get MemoryMappedFile to do what I want but it's not going my way at the moment.  I will look into your other suggestions next.  Part of the problem is that this functionality was requested several months after project was delivered, and I worry that working in some msg passing strategy might be a significant overhaul compared to the perceived benefit.

Comment: Peter, I ended up using your solution, and implemented one of your suggestions, the named pipe.  This was a handful for me at my experience level but I took my time and got everything working smoothly.  Thanks very much for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

(1) If you can figure out a way to publish an event from a Java process into the windows event log, you can definitely set up your .net app to watch for specific event types

(2) If you can arrange for the .net app to watch for files being created in a particular directory using FileSystemWatcher (maybe in %TEMP%), you can have your Java process write a file that contains whatever info you wish to pass.